# BMO2 1995 Question 1 - Solve the equation for positive integers (a,b,c)

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, contest-math

Find all triples of positive integers (a, b, c) such that

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{a} \right)\left( 1 + \frac{1}{b} \right)\left( 1 + \frac{1}{c} \right) = 2 $$

I tried to expand, yielding $ a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+1 = abc $, but I couldn't go anywhere from here.

This problem clearly involves using the fact that $a, b, c$ are positive integers, since there are three variables and only one equation. It would be great if someone also addressed this condition and maybe tried to solve the problem for other requirements, like when $a, b, c$ are positive or negative integers.

Finally - can anyone post or link other such problems which involves a mix of algebra manipulation and number theory. I would really appreciate it.

(Here is the full paper: https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo2-1995.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Considering cases works pretty well. If the product is to be $2$, then at least one of the numbers must be less than $4$, and all numbers are clearly $>1$.

Order the numbers so that $a\le b\le c$. Then $a = 2$ or $a=3$. If $a=2$, then $4\le b\le 6$ (since $b=2$ or $b=3$ produces a product too large, and if $b=7$ then $c\ge 7$ and the product is too small). This gives the three solutions $(2,4,15)$, $(2,5,9)$, and $(2,6,7)$. Alternatively, if $a=3$, a similar analysis yields the solutions $(3,3,8)$ and $(3,4,5)$.

So there are five essentially different solutions: $(2,4,15)$, $(2,5,9)$, $(2,6,7)$, $(3,3,8)$, and $(3,4,5)$.

Comment: Great solution! Do you think there are any other ways of doing which involve some clever factorisation?

Comment: Perhaps someone else will come up with one, but they seem complicated. For example, $b$ must divide $(a+1)(c+1)$, ...

Comment: *If the product is to be $2,$ then at least one of the numbers must be less than* $4~-~$ The fact that $\sqrt[3]2\simeq\dfrac54$ stands at the basis of the beautiful approximation $3000_{12}\simeq5000_{10},$ or, alternately, $12^4\simeq2\cdot10^4,$ which relate duodecimal thousands and myriads to their decimal counterparts.

Comment: @Lucian:  from $\sqrt[3]2\approx\dfrac54,$ I get $2000_4\approx1000_5$; how do you get $3000_{12}\approx5000_{10}$ ?

Comment: Also I get the well-known $10000000000_2\approx1000_{10}$; perhaps you were merely saying $3000_{12}\approx{5000}_{10}$ follows from the similar fact $\sqrt[4]2\approx\dfrac65$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Using $10^3\simeq2^{10},~$ we first rewrite $5\cdot10^3$ as $5\cdot2^{10},~$ then we split $2^{10}$ into $2^{4+6}=2^4\cdot2^6,~$ and employ $5\cdot2^4=80\simeq81=3^4,~$ from which the result immediately follows.

Comment: @Lucian:  thank you for the explanation.  I get it now