# Find all positive integer triples $(a, b, c)$ such that $(1+ \frac{1}{a})×(1+\frac{1}{b})×(1+\frac{1}{c})=2$?

Tags: inequality

I was thinking about removing the brackets and denominators but i am not sure how I would follow. How can I do this?

Comment: Thought: Maybe you can use $(1+\frac{1}{a}) = \frac{a+1}{a}$?

Comment: I'd start by noting that $\sqrt[3] 2\approx 1.26$ so the least of the three integers can't exceed $4$.  After that, just go case by case (on the least of the three integers).

Comment: If any of $a, b,$ or $c = 1$ then the product $> 2$, but (3,4,5) is a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BMO2 1995 Question 1 - Solve the equation for positive integers (a,b,c)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900092/bmo2-1995-question-1-solve-the-equation-for-positive-integers-a-b-c) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(1%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D)×(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%7D)×(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%7D)%3D2%24&p=1)